# How to calculate slope of Pandas dataframe column based on previous N rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scipy

I have the following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [2, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, 5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       col1
0      2
1      5
2      6
3      5
4      4
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9      7
10     5
```

I need to calculate the slope of the previous N rows from **col1** and save the slope value in a separate column (call it **slope**). The desired output may look like the following: (Given slope values below are just random numbers for the sake of example.)

```
       col1  slope
0      2
1      5
2      6
3      5
4      4     3
5      6     4
6      7     5
7      8     2
8      9     4
9      7     6
10     5     5
```

So, in the row with the index number 4, the slope is 3 and it is the slope of [2, 5, 6, 5, 4].

Is there an elegant way of doing it without using for loop?

---

ADDENDUM:

Based on the accepted answer below, in case you get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

It may be so that the index of your dataframe is maybe not numerical. The following modification makes it work then:

```
df['slope'] = df['col1'].rolling(5).apply(lambda s: linregress(range(5), s.values)[0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)+`apply` and [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html):

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress

df['slope'] = df['col1'].rolling(5).apply(lambda s: linregress(s.reset_index())[0])

print(df)
```

output:

```
    col1  slope
0      2    NaN
1      5    NaN
2      6    NaN
3      5    NaN
4      4    0.4
5      6    0.0
6      7    0.3
7      8    0.9
8      9    1.2
9      7    0.4
10     5   -0.5
```

Comment: @mozway Thank you very much for the answer. I am trying to make it work but I get the following error: "TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''". What can be the reason? I do know that col1 is not a type of string in my dataframe. But the index of my dataframe is not 0,1,2,3,4,.. . Can it be related to that?

Comment: Yes, it currently used the index as x values, you can use `range(len(s))` instead (`linregress(range(len(s)), s)`) as the exact `x` doesn't matter if you only care that it is evenly spaced by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Let us do with `numpy`

```
def slope_numpy(x,y):
    fit = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    return np.poly1d(fit)[0]
df.col1.rolling(5).apply(lambda x : slope_numpy(range(5),x))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     3.6
5     5.2
6     5.0
7     4.2
8     4.4
9     6.6
10    8.2
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why does your solution return different results than the one suggested by @mozway?

Comment: Those are not the coefficients of the regression, but the intercept (the slopes are given by `np.polyfit` directly, the first value of the output)